# How to prevent Google Scholar from merging two different papers?

Tags: google-scholar

I have two papers published at the same IEEE conference (at the same year).

Since they have been indexed in GS, they are being merged every few days. That is, I manually need to "unmerge" them, just for GS to automatically merge them again a few days later.

I'm not sure why this happens. They have completely different names. Perhaps the reason is that IEEE has page numbers of 1-9 for all papers that year (i.e., they didn't actually allocate page numbers but just had 1-9 for all).

How can I make GS stop merging these papers?

Comment: What makes all these people think that this website is google scholar support central?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - not a support center, but a forum with many people that are using GS and may have encountered this before. (be sure that I did try to search that before asking here).

Comment: That seems like a bad idea for IEEE to do the page numbers like that.  Evidently Google is assuming, not unreasonably, that (journal, volume, issue, page number) will uniquely identity a single paper, and I would guess that a lot of other systems make the same assumption.

Comment: Complain at your conference - this is really bad practice!

Answer (score 3):

[Update: Multiple users have reported that this doesn't work.]

1. Go to your Google Scholar profile and bring up the add article dropdown, click on "Configure article updates": [image: Google scholar add article dropdown menu]
2. Select the radio button for "Don't automatically update my profile" and click the "Update settings" button: [image: Google scholar configure article updates page]
3. When Scholar wants to merge your papers, instead of going ahead it will send an email to ask if that is the correct course of action.

Comment: I tried that. They are still merged automatically :(.

Comment: Oh. Then that seems to be a bug (or, at least, functionality that is otherwise than the user would expect) that should be reported. But Google Scholar doesn't seem to have a bug report page.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is anything that can be done.   I too have this same problem, except in my case GS wants to merge two similar titles (even though they have different years). Repeatedly unmerge these two articles, a couple of days later GS merges them back.

Turning off auto-updates does not affect this behavior.