# Google Scholar has erroneously merged two distinct papers with similar titles, along with their citations. How can this be corrected?

Tags: publications, citations, authorship, google-scholar, bibliometrics

Two of my papers have the same name except for Year from the shared task; both papers are completely different. Google Scholar has merged both papers, due to which the new author from the 2nd paper has not got any citation in their profile. How can we correct the issue? Can we contact Google Scholar?

```
Paper 1 : XXXXX 2019: YYYYY
Paper 2 : XXXXXX 2020: YYYYY
XXXXX and YYYYY are part of the paper titles.
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to do this. Similar questions asked in the past: [How to prevent Google Scholar from merging two different papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/103746/68109), [How to split two papers that Google Scholar incorrectly thinks are the same paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38779/68109)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Change the title of one of the papers.

Comment: Do the techniques discussed in previous answers still work? Google is continuously updating its products and their UI, so that can't be taken as a given.